# tar + how to extract from /var/tmp in order to place the directories under /

Tags: solaris, tar

I work with solaris 9 machine

In order to extract the **list.tar** file I need to change directory to /

And from there I do:

```
 tar -xvf list.tar
```

Example

```
Cd /

tar -xvf list.tar


 x usr/local/cds/api/SNMP/s_trap.pl, 7644 bytes, 15 tape blocks
 x usr/local/cww/lib/Storage/SW.pl, 76537 bytes, 150 tape blocks
 x etc/cs/shared/functions.pl, 13801 bytes, 27 tape blocks
 x etc/cp/shared/globals.pl, 4042 bytes, 8 tape blocks
```

my question

how to do the

```
 tar –xvf from /var/tmp ? ( is it possible )
```

if I do that from /var/tmp ,  then tar will create the directorates under /var/tmp , in place to create then under /

example

```
   /var/tmp/usr/…….
```

solaris tar usuage:

```
      Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x}[BDeEFhilmnopPqTvw@[0-7]][bfk][X...] [blocksize] [tarfile] [size] [exclude-file...] {file | -I include-file | -C directory file}...
```

Comment: what paths do you want the restored files to have?

Comment: the path are /usr/local/..../..../....    and /usr/cs/shared/..../... etc

Comment: Solaris 9 tar has the C flag only for the c and r operations, not for the x operation. The `cd / && tar -xvf /path/to/file.tar` command in the answers below are your best alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GNU `tar` doc's (`man tar`)

```
 -C, --directory DIR
       change to directory DIR
```

So you command should be:

```
tar -C / -xvf list.tar
```

If you don't have `-C`

```
# /var/tmp
(x=$PWD;cd /;tar xvf $x/list.tar)
```

Comment: -C flag not in solaris ( please advice what the same flag on solaris )

Comment: completed for missing `-C`

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/tmp
(cd / && tar xvf -) < file.tar
```

Or use the standard pax command:

```
(cd / && pax -rv) < file.tar
```

For compresses ones:

```
cd /var/tmp
gunzip < file.tar.gz | (cd / && tar xvf -)
```

Of course, you can also do:

```
cd / && tar xvf /var/tmp/file.tar
```

Comment: I think it will better to use solaris flags